# How to auto complete a task in asana via intellij

Tags: asana, intellij-13

I am using Intellij IDE.

When i complete a task, i commit my work, I would expect that asana would mark my task as complete, but it doesnt.

Is there a way to make it mark as complete, and put my commit notes on the task ?

Comment: In the API you can set the `completed` property to `true` - you could look at the source of the IntelliJ plugin and see if it does that I suppose?

Comment: how do i look in the intellij source code?

Comment: I'm afraid I know basically nothing about IntelliJ, just the Asana API. :-( All I know is the Asana API supports marking a task complete, so IntelliJ *could* do it, if the plugin supports it.